# Join Method String Manipulation Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I need a bit help for this  exercise regarding of using Join Method String Manipulation on Visual basic (VB.Net) where it deals with a ReDim Method.

The goal is to make a program that uses an inputbox.

The inputbox must be loop and shows one word at a time until it reaches the limit by pressing an assigned command.

In short there's no fixed loop, it will depend on the user on how many loops were covered.

Once done, join method works based on how many user inputs. Example: "Hello+Hi+testing+one+two+Three+four+five"

Here's my code which I couldn't figured out until now.

```
    Dim inputtext As String
    Dim counter As Integer
    Dim language() As String


 Do Until inputtext = "."
        inputtext = InputBox("Enter the language as many as you can")
        MsgBox(inputtext)
        counter = counter + 1
    Loop

    ReDim Preserve language(inputtext)


    inputtext = String.Join("+", language)
    MsgBox(inputtext.ToString)
```

Comment: Are you specifically looking for a solution with `ReDim`? A better alternative would be using generic list of string.

Comment: Yes a solution for ReDim, but I've understand the purpose only just the way where it will be put the code and should be added "preserve" to avoid erasures of the collected declared arrays.

Comment: Redim preserve is memory inefficient. List of string is memory efficient. The choice is yours.

Answer (score 0):

As Per your description I think What you need is as follow:
See I have updated your **Do..Until** code block.

```
 Dim inputtext As String=""
    Dim counter As Integer =0
    Dim language(0) As String


 Do Until inputtext = "."
        inputtext = InputBox("Enter the language as many as you can")
        ReDim Preserve language(UBound(language) + 1)
        language(counter) = inputtext 
        MsgBox(inputtext)
        counter = counter + 1

    Loop

   ' ReDim Preserve language(inputtext)


    inputtext = String.Join("+", language)
    MsgBox(inputtext.ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, however I got a null error in the code of language(counter) = inputtext on the Do Until Loop

Comment: This won't work because you don't initialize the `language` array. Why not use a `List<string>` instead? These are much easier to work with when adding elements at runtime.

Comment: Dan Puzey: Well we are not yet covered the discussion of List<String> type so basically Declaring Dimension purpose only.

Comment: @JamesCarloValdeavilla Try this code now It is working perfect for me.

Comment: Yes, thank you for another solution code it works so one thing that my code is really closer which lacks of few arrangement of pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You should redim the array and add `inputtext` inside the loop, otherwise you will only add the last value. You should also test for the termination value and only add if different:

```
Dim inputtext As String
Dim counter As Integer
Dim language() As String

Do Until inputtext = "."
    inputtext = InputBox("Enter the language as many as you can")
    If inputtext <> "." Then
        MsgBox(inputtext)
        ReDim Preserve language(counter)
        language(counter) = inputtext
        counter = counter + 1
    End If
Loop

inputtext = String.Join("+", language)
MsgBox(inputtext.ToString)
```

Comment: Thank you for solution, it works :) well I need to review more advance in this kind of string manipulation.